# Do atoms in a molecule actually keep rotating freely in case they have sigma bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

While reading about cis-trans isomers I found the concept of free rotation of atoms.it says 2 atoms connected by sigma bond do not have trans sis isomer because of free rotation.while in case of pi bond free rotation is not possible. My question is : do we mean actual rotation of atoms in molecule when we say free rotation? Does the rotation happen spontaneously? What things are responsible for the rotation? Or is it just a concept to understand the concept of cis-trans isomers?

Comment: Are you referring to *molecular rotation*? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/molecule/rotrig.html

Comment: No I am not referring to molecular rotation

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Will answer.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64219/when-is-rotation-around-double-bonds-to-form-cis-trans-isomers-allowed

Comment: With a molecule the whole thing can rotate both in the gas phase and in solution. Additionally **groups** of atoms within a molecule can rotate provided there is enough thermal (or light) energy to overcome any steric interaction from bulky groups or bond energy that will otherwise prevent this. Thus C-C bonds rotate relatively easily at room temperature but C=C do not as thermal energy is not enough to overcome bond energy.

Answer (score 1):

You really are referring to *molecular [conformations](https://www.britannica.com/science/conformation-molecular-structure)*:

> **Conformation**, any one of the infinite number of possible spatial arrangements of atoms in a molecule that result from rotation of its
>   constituent groups of atoms *about single bonds*.

Below are given two possible (out of many!) conformations of the ethane $\ce{C2H6}$ molecule:

[image: Conformation]

[image: Conformation 2]

The single $\sigma$ bond allows free rotation around the inter-nuclear axis of the two $\ce{C}$ atoms. One consequence is that *around the single bond no cis-trans isomers can exist*.

But if we add a $\pi$ bond, so we have a *double bond* and *ethene* $\ce{C2H4}$, then the methylene groups can no longer freely rotate about the bond.

That's because the *electron probability density* added by the $\pi$ bond doesn't lie on the inter-nuclear axis, but above and below it. Double bonds, and by extension also triple bonds, are **rigid**, with respect to rotation of the atoms they bond. *This can give rise to cis-trans isomers.*

*Below:* highly schematised rendition of the electron density of a $\pi$ bond:

[image: Pi bond]

Comment: It doesn't exactly answer question, only elaborates on what OP told. Actual rotation depends on temperature.

Comment: Sorry to say that I still have questions.my question is that the "free rotation" is it like happening all the time? Do the c atoms keep rotating always? Is it spontaneous ?

Comment: @user136782: Hi. Did you read the link I provided? The term 'free rotation' is a little misleading, as different parts of the molecule will still electronically repel each other. But the impossibility of cis-trans isomers about a single bond does stem from the *possibility* of rotation about the inter-nuclear axis.